# Accessing correct fulfilment request with intent

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I hope someone can help me with this.
I have two separate intents news and weather in my dialog flow agent.
I have different input parameters for both of them.
And I am using two separate API for each of them. 
When I use both of them separately it works fine. 
but when I try to combine both of them in one agent it does not show relevant output based on question. i.e if I ask question regarding weather it shows me news. 
Is there any way I can fix it.right now it goes directly to the second request. Here is  my code:

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const http = require('http');
const host = 'api.worldweatheronline.com';
const wwoApiKey = '0cb58ac2d82f484fa75185834191912';
const NewsAPI = require('newsapi');
const newsapi = new NewsAPI('63756dc5caca424fb3d0343406295021');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) =>
{

    var agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    // Get the city and date from the request
    let city = request.body.queryResult.parameters['geo-city'];// city is a required param
     // Get the date for the weather forecast (if present)
    let date = 'date';
    if (request.body.queryResult.parameters['date']) {
                                                    date = request.body.queryResult.parameters['date'];
                                                    console.log('Date: ' + date);
                                                    }
  //Get the search criteria from the request    
  const search = request.body.queryResult.parameters['search'];
  console.log(search);

  //Map the correct intent 
    let intentMap = new Map();
        intentMap.set('misty.weather',getweather );
        intentMap.set('misty.news', getnews);

        agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

});
//Weather reuest function 
function getweather(agent,city,date)
{
  callWeatherApi(city, date).then((output) => {
                                            response.json({ 'fulfillmentText': output }); // Return the results of the weather API to Dialogflow
                                            }).catch(() => {
                                                            response.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I don't know the weather but I hope it's good!` });
                                                            });

}

// news request function 
function getnews(search,agent)
{
callNewsApi(search).then((output) => {
                            console.log("Indide request");

                            response.json({ 'fulfillmentText': output }); // Return the results of the news API to Dialogflow
                        }).catch((error) => {
                                        console.log(error);
                                        response.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I don't know the news but I hope it's good!` });
                                    });

}

// API call for weather 
function callWeatherApi (city, date) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create the path for the HTTP request to get the weather
    let path = '/premium/v1/weather.ashx?format=json&num_of_days=1' +
      '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(city) + '&key=' + wwoApiKey + '&date=' + date;
    console.log('API Request: ' + host + path);

    // Make the HTTP request to get the weather
    http.get({host: host, path: path}, (response) => {
      let body = ''; // var to store the response chunks
      response.on('data', (d) => { body += d; }); // store each response chunk
      response.on('end', () => {
        // After all the data has been received parse the JSON for desired data
        let response = JSON.parse(body);
        let forecast = response['data']['weather'][0];
        let location = response['data']['request'][0];
        let conditions = response['data']['current_condition'][0];
        let currentConditions = conditions['weatherDesc'][0]['value'];

        // Create response
        let output = `Current conditions in the ${location['type']} 
        ${location['query']} are ${currentConditions} with a projected high of
        ${forecast['maxtempC']}°C or ${forecast['maxtempF']}°F and a low of 
        ${forecast['mintempC']}°C or ${forecast['mintempF']}°F on 
        ${forecast['date']}.`;

        // Resolve the promise with the output text
        console.log(output);
        resolve(output);
      });
      response.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(`Error calling the weather API: ${error}`);
        reject();
      });
    });
  });
}
//API call for news
function callNewsApi(search) 
{

                    console.log("Inside api call");
                    console.log(search);

                     return newsapi.v2.topHeadlines
                    (
                            { 
                            source:'CBC News',
                            q:search,
                            langauge: 'en',        
                            country: 'ca',

                            }
                        ).then (response => {



                                                                    // var to store the response chunks
                                                    // store each response chunk

                                                            console.log(response);

                                                            var articles = response['articles'][0];
                                                            console.log(articles);
                                                            console.log("Inside responce call");
                                                    // Create response
                                                    var output = `Current news in the '${search}' with following title is  ${articles['titile']} which says that ${articles['description']}`;
                                                    console.log(output);
                                                    return output; 
                                                                    });


}
```

It is giving me a reference error at line 51 and 42. I suspect I am missing a perameter to display the output.

```
function getnews(search,agent)
{
callNewsApi(search).then((output) => {
                            console.log("Indide request");

                            response.json({ 'fulfillmentText': output }); // Return the results of the news API to Dialogflow
                        }).catch((error) => {
                                        console.log(error);
                                        response.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I don't know the news but I hope it's good!` });
                                    });

}
```

it shows highlights near response.json and says that response not defined.

Comment: can you share more code, where you are combining both the intent handler in one API ?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar added more details to the code. and exact error I am getting

Answer (score 0):

When I am reading your code, it looks like you're posting 2 Cloud Functions, while via the Dialogflow console, you can only set one webhook URL or Cloud Function. Therefore your approach should be that your webhook URL (pointing to a VM, Container etc..) or Cloud Function; contains code that behaves like a 'router'.

You will create the WebhookClient just once.
All parameters can be retrieved out of the **queryResult** object.

The intentMap could look something like this:

```
  let intentMap = new Map();   
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('misty.weather', getWeather);
  intentMap.set('misty.news', getNews);   

  function getNews() { .. }
  function getWeather() {..}
```

I've an example Dialogflow / AOG project with a (Google Cloud, Cloud Function), you can have a look at:

https://github.com/savelee/dialogflow-aog-tvguide/

With this cloud function:
https://github.com/savelee/dialogflow-aog-tvguide/blob/master/cloudfunction/tvguide/index-old.js

Comment: your answer makes sense to me I was making two retquest under the same http call. I took a look on your example and tried to make changes to my code, now it is pointing to the correct api request function. but it is not returning any output under my fulfillment text it is giving me an error reference error. don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I have edited my question with updated code. can you suggest any changes to fix the error.